# tdplyr - (TDR_E1001) using fastload

Tags: r, teradata

I am getting some weird errors, when I try to upload a data.frame to the Teradata database using td_fastload() in R.

The copy_to() method works for smaller sets without any issues, just takes a while... but td_fastload() for bigger sets don't work, here is what I am getting, what does this mean ?

my command is:

`td_fastload(con, df = TEST55, table.name = "TEST55", overwrite = TRUE )`

and the errors are:

````
Error: In value[[3L]](cond):
[tdplyr - (TDR_E1001)] Error: In value[[3L]](cond):
[tdplyr - (TDR_E1001)] Error in obtainRows(res, FALSE, params): Argument params class character differs from the required data.frame or list

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In td_fastload(con, df = TEST55, table.name = 'TEST55', overwrite = TRUE):
[tdplyr - (TDR_W1011)] Setting 'overwrite = TRUE' will drop existing table 'TEST55' and recreate it with new schema. 
2: In sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim), ...) :
  one argument not used by format 'Error in obtainRows(res, FALSE, params): Argument params class character differs from the required data.frame or list
'
3: In sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim), ...) :
  one argument not used by format 'Error: In value[[3L]](cond):
[tdplyr - (TDR_E1001)] Error in obtainRows(res, FALSE, params): Argument params class character differs from the required data.frame or list```
````

Comment: Sometimes when you are memory constrained odd errors are reported. Maybe try specifying `batch.size=50000` to see if that helps.

Comment: same error / I tried that before and even with just trying to upload a small file with 5 records, and always get the same errors.

Comment: I think this has something to do with file Character type... the ones that does work is: application/octet-stream; charset=binary / but the one that does not work is: us-ascii ?  I mean by the time I import it into R, it's all just a Data.Frame and I can't see anything weird.

Comment: but also am not sure, Very weird!